# How to Query a Data Extension and Update the Subscriber list at the Child Business Unit Level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

How to Query a Data Extension and Update the Subscriber list at the Child Business Unit Level without using landing pages?

Comment: What code set have you tried so far?

Comment: I've only been able to update the subscribers table from landing pages that have ampscript in them.  I this scenario I don't have any landing pages. I have a data extension that I need to query periodically and update the subscribers table w/o a landing page.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how I would do it, but the answer is what you would call "hacktastic".  You will need to set up (within the email application):

1. A query activity to get the data out of the data extension, and put it into a new results data extension.
2. Data Extract Activity to get the data out of the results data extension and put it into the ET holding "tank".
3. A File Transfer to get the file from the holding tank and move it to a more accessible folder.
4. Another File Transfer activity to move it to the Import Folder (this may be optional depending on how #3 goes, but FT activites also deal with decrypting, unzipping, etc.).
5. An Import Activity to import the subscribers list.

After all that is set up, you would toggle over to the automation studio application and set all these steps up in order there, as well as schedule the automation.

That should work.  I hope this helps!

Comment: When the data extension was initially loaded with data the subscriber key was not available.  I would like to update all rows in that data extension with the subscriber key (which will obviously be different for each row by reading the email addr).  Can this be done using server side javascript activity?

Comment: Ignore comment ago.

Comment: When creating an import activity to update the Subscriber table, there is no option to update the unsubscribe date.  You can only update Email Address (required), DONOTUSE, Status, HTML Email, Subscriber Key (required).  Is there another way to update the unsubscribe date?

Comment: Please post this as a new question.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41084/updating-unsubscribe-date-using-import-activity

Comment: The above process works if you want to update the subscribers list at the enterprise business unit level.  If you attempt to update the Child Business Unit it fails (by creating an import activity in the Child BU)