# Updating unsubscribe date using import activity

Tags: marketing-cloud

When creating an import activity to update the Subscriber table, there is no option to update the unsubscribe date. You can only update Email Address (required), DONOTUSE, Status, HTML Email, Subscriber Key (required). Is there another way to update the unsubscribe date?

Comment: The note above is for attempting to update the Child Business Units All Subscribers list