# Emailaddress not updating in All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are updating a customers email address and it is being updated in the  main customer DE.

However when we send an email to that DE the customer it is still receiving it to their old email address which is still stored as the old email in All Subscribers.

Our SFMC setup has our unique identifier as the subscriberkey and not email address

If you have an updated email address in the DE does it not update All Subscribers when you send to that DE? (looks like it doesnt).

Is there a setting or way of forcing it to update All Subscribers when we try to send to the updated email?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is by design. Marketing Cloud's email app uses a Subscriber model; it will send to the email address defined in the Subscriber record.

The only solution that I'm aware of is the somewhat awkward method of exporting the DE, then re-importing it using an Import Activity.

Refer to the procedural steps documented in this answer: [How to Query a Data Extension and Update the Subscriber list at the Child Business Unit Level?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40156/how-to-query-a-data-extension-and-update-the-subscriber-list-at-the-child-busine#answer-40271)

Comment: Thanks - I thought this was the case. We are currently working on an automation that exports the updates from the DE and then re-imports them into all subscribers with the updated email address.