# Updating All Subscribers List with query, extract and import

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, data-extract

I have followed instructions from this link :

[How to Query a Data Extension and Update the Subscriber list at the Child Business Unit Level?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40156/how-to-query-a-data-extension-and-update-the-subscriber-list-at-the-child-busine)

Our current configuration allows existing users to update their email address.
This page is hosted on a e commerce engine - Hybris
Issue is that when this is updated , it is not updated in SFMC, hence all they do not receive future communication.

Issue is that the final step, import activity keeps failing (csv import).  Here is a screen shot of the error log:

[image]

I will appreciate any help in solving this.

**EDIT**

I ran the first iteration and it worked. However we I tried to combine all five steps into a automation, it failed.

[image: Import Failure 2]

What I do know is that those are the values for my subscriber key, which I have manually mapped. I have checked the file on the FTP and it contains these values.

Comment: FieldNotFound _EmailAddress.. Is this field present in your csv file?

Comment: Yes the field is there. However, in the Data Extension it is call EmailAddress... not sure if I have to rename it to "_EmailAddress_". It is the only required field.

Comment: Ok you're importing data into DE. try to do manual import and use map field by manually option. Also, its required to match Import file field with DE field and in case its not matching then you can use map field by manually option.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried the above and now the import is failing with a different error code "Not Found". I am posting this in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you wanting to update the All Subscribers list (*not a data extension*), the correct field name is **Email Address** (*note: the space*).  You will need to rename the header in your file to match or choose to map fields manually in your import configuration.  If subscriber key is enabled in your account, you will also need to supply a column named **subscriber key** along with the corresponding subscriber key values for each emailaddress.

In order to update the status, your file must contain a column named **Status**.  The status values will need to be either "active" or "unsubscribe".  That part is tricky, since the subscriber status in the Platform appears as "Active" or "Unsubscribed".

Refer to the following link for more information on configuring import activities.
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/
https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers1/imports/

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried the above and now the import is failing with a different error code "Not Found".  I am posting this in the question

Comment: What is the update type on you import activity?  If you search all subscribers by subscriber key, are you able to find records for 1073362717, 1073362718, 1073362719, & 1073362720 ?  Also, can you provide a a screenshot of your source file?

Comment: You are a star!! For some silly reason I had set the import activity to update only! Thank you so much @David Devoy!